# Javascript Array as WCF Webservice Parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

I need to pass a simple Javascript array to my wcf ajax webservice:

```
var array = new Array();
array["ParamA"] = "xyz";
array["12344"] = "9";
myNamespace.DoSomething(array);
```

This this my WCF method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void DoSomething(object values)
```

"values" is an empty array when it is called from javascript with my values.
What is the best approach to pass a simple list of KeyValuePairs to my webservice?

Comment: Do you see the values in the JSON request if you proxy the call?

Comment: I checked it and the values are empty. So it seems I have to use another approach.

Comment: Can you change the parameter type to Array and then try to pass the array by using a JSON serializer on the client as your WCF service's Request Format is set to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void DoSomething(Dictionary<string, object> values)
```

must be called in javascript like this:

var params = [{ "Key": "A", "Value": 5}, { "Key": "B", "Value": "Test}]

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"values":' + JSON.stringify(params) + '}',
    ...
```

This can of course be simplified:

```
var parameters = [{ "A": 5}, { "B": "Test"}];

var dictionary = new Array();
for (var i in parameters) {
   var key = Object.keys(args[i])[0];
   var value = args[i][key];
   dictionary.push({ "Key": key, "Value": value });
} 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"values":' + JSON.stringify(dictionary) + '}',
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take Javascript object

```
var obj = {
    Key: "xyz",
    Value: "9"
};

Array objArray = new Array();
objArray.push(obj); 

$.ajax({
//Add necessary detail here               
data:  JSON.stringify(objArray);
});
```

In service layer replace object with array of NameValuePair

```
public void DoSomething(NameValuePair[] values)
{}

[DataContract]
public class NameValuePair
{
[DataMember]
public string Key {get;set;}
[DataMember]
public string Value {get;set;}
}
```