# Posting to WCF json endpoint with angular

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, wcf, angularjs

I am trying to post to a WCF json service endpoint from angular but have been unsuccessful in my attempts. I have verified the service is working by other means and working for the specified URL.

Using firebug I can see the request being output as such:

> NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
>   http://www.myapi.com/V1/Service.svc/Authenticate?Password=password&UserName=username"

angular code

```
app.service('UserService', function ($http) {
this.GetLoginStatus = function (AuthenticateRequest) {
    $http({
        url: APIURL + "/Authenticate",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        params: AuthenticateRequest,
        data: {
            'Code': 'test data'
        }
    });
};
```

});

WCF Iservice

```
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
Method = "POST",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[OperationContract]
AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest Request);
```

Request definition

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthenticateRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do you setup/define the basic auth on your service? You are sure the auth string is good? Do you use postman in chrome?

Comment: I updated my code and removed that line. I did use postman.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with WCF, but isn't the wrapped() style for adding XML elements? If the intention is for the api to just speak json, maybe you do not want that? Also, I can't help but think you might want to send the content in the body, in the data property and not as query params (as the service is expecting POST).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this done by stringfy-ing a javascript object.

```
    Service.js

        angular.module('myModule').factory('serviceFac', ['$http', '$q', 
function (a, b) 
    {   var taskMergeServiceNameSet = "WebServuice.svc/Tasks/SetTasks";
            return {
                setTasksMerge: function (taskIds, action) {

                 var objArray = '';
                 var obj = {
                        taskIds: taskIds,
                        action: action,
                        userName: "ss"
                  };
                 objArray = new Array();
                 objArray.push(obj);
                 var deferred = b.defer();
                 a({
                   url: taskMergeServiceNameSet,
                   method: 'POST',
                   headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
                   data: JSON.stringify(objArray)
                  }
                  ).sucess(function (data) { deferred.resolve(data) })
                  .error(function (msg, code) { deferred.reject(msg) });    
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Service Contract

```
ServiceContract Interface

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITasks
{
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json ,
      ResponseFormat =   WebMessageFormat.Json, 
      UriTemplate = "Tasks/SetTasksForMerge")]
    string CreateNewTaks(valObj[] values);        
}

[DataContract]
public class valObj
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string taskIds { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string action { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    }
```

post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188315/javascript-array-as-wcf-webservice-parameter) helped me a lot. please let me know if you suceed in passing a JSON string