# Angular $http post to WCF service null argument

Tags: c#, json, wcf, angularjs, firefox

I have simple angular js app. I have a simple authenticate method. When the method is executed in internet explorer the WCF method receives the argument with the data. When the ame code is executed from firefox the argument is null on the server.

```
$http({
    url: Url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: AuthenticateRequest
});
```

WCF Method

```
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    Method = "*",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest AuthenticateRequest);
```

Fiddler IE Info

```
POST http://www.api.com:56586/V1/Service.svc/json/Authenticate HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://www.api.com:54567/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:56586
Content-Length: 45
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"UserName":"username","Password":"password"}
```

Firefox Fiddler Info

```
OPTIONS http://www.api.com:56586/V1/Service.svc/json/Authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: www.api.com:56586
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://www.api.com:54567
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-requested-with
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: FF is sending an `OPTIONS`request instead of `POST`. Therefore you don`t get the payload. Do you have your web app and web service hosted on the same host/port? Are you getting any info in the browser javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this done by stringfy-ing a javascript object.

```
    Service.js

        angular.module('myModule').factory('serviceFac', ['$http', '$q', 
function (a, b) 
    {   var taskMergeServiceNameSet = "WebServuice.svc/Tasks/SetTasks";
            return {
                setTasksMerge: function (taskIds, action) {

                 var objArray = '';
                 var obj = {
                        taskIds: taskIds,
                        action: action,
                        userName: "ss"
                  };
                 objArray = new Array();
                 objArray.push(obj);
                 var deferred = b.defer();
                 a({
                   url: taskMergeServiceNameSet,
                   method: 'POST',
                   headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
                   data: JSON.stringify(objArray)
                  }
                  ).sucess(function (data) { deferred.resolve(data) })
                  .error(function (msg, code) { deferred.reject(msg) });    
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Service Contract

```
ServiceContract Interface

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITasks
{
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json ,
      ResponseFormat =   WebMessageFormat.Json, 
      UriTemplate = "Tasks/SetTasksForMerge")]
    string CreateNewTaks(valObj[] values);        
}

[DataContract]
public class valObj
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string taskIds { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string action { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    }
```

post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188315/javascript-array-as-wcf-webservice-parameter) helped me a lot. please let me know if you suceed in passing a JSON string